# Overriding styles in <td> with a style in <tr>

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to override the style in `<td>` tags with a style in `<tr>` tags?
I'm thinking of something like below. The color #AAAAAA in tr should also cover/overwrite the background-image in td.

```html
<table>
  <tr style="background-color:#AAAAAA !important;">
    <td style="background-color:#FF0000; background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300); background-repeat: no-repeat;">test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above unfortunately still shows the red background and the background image.

Comment: "*The color #AAAAAA in tr should also cover/overwrite the background-image in td*" - What makes you think this? The `td` will have a higher index in the HTML's flow. It's "above" the `tr`

Comment: Simply don't expect a parent element to overlay its own child element and you're fine. Research about the `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements.

Comment: No, this is not possible. In terms of their backgrounds, you can think of the TD as a sheet of paper, that is laid on top of a different sheet of paper, the TR. So unless your first sheet of paper was transparent/opaque, you can not expect to the the color of the second sheet of paper _below_.

Comment: What is stopping you from overwriting the TD background specifically, with the one you want instead? Are the inline styles the problem, or what problem _exactly_ needs solving here?

Comment: @CBroe Changing the TD backgrounds would require extensive CSS and overall layout changes. Overwriting it by server-side injected TR-style when required for a certain row would have made things much easier.

Comment: @lmoly then, instead of using important on the `tr` given you use (for some strange reason inline `style`) use `!important` in your stylesheet on the `td` element `td.someSpecialCaseClass { background: transparent !important; }` . Anyways, `!important` should be avoided at all costs. And inline `style` too.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I know, but the HTML and CSS is 15 years old and wasn't written by me.

Comment: @lmoly so use `transparent !important` on the TD then (as suggested).

Comment: Will the TR _only_ have inline styling, when you are trying to overwrite the background of the table cells? If so, then `tr[style] td[style] { background: none !important; }` should already be enough, to eliminate the TD background, so that the background of the TR will "shine through."

Comment: Only with some JS code to remove or change  TD style unwanted background information